# Entity is empty in formModifier on form events

Tags: php, symfony, events

English is not my native language, sorry for that.

I have a meet entity (rendezVous) and in this entity, i have two others mapped entities doctor(docteur) and customer(client).

I want to change the list of doctors when choosing a customer.

For that, I create a form events in my RendezVousType, but the problem is when i choose a customer, the Client entity is empty in my formModifier.

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Client',
            'placeholder' => '',
        ));

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Client $client = null) {
        $idEspece = null === $client ? 0 : $client->getId();

        $form->add('docteur', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Docteur',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'query_builder' => function (DocteurRepository $er) use ($idEspece) {
                return $er->getByClientEspece($idEspece);
            },
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getClient());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $client = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
        }
    );
}
```

When I set a default value for $idEspece, the query builder returns the correct list.

Answer (score 0):

Your form type is valid but Symfony don't do that automatically using ajax, then the doctor only appear after form submission.

Then to get the list of doctors using ajax you need add some additional logic.

Firstly, create a action in your controller to get the list of doctors and return a json

```
/**
 * @Route(name="get_doctors", path="/get_doctors" )
 */
public function getDoctorsAction(Request $request)
{
    $client = $request->get('rendez_vous')['client'];
    $clients = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Docteur')
                    ->getByClientEspece($client)
                    ->select('s.id', 's.name')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getArrayResult();
    $indexedClients = array_column($clients, 'name', 'id');

    return new JsonResponse($indexedClients);
}
```

Add the following jquery plugin in your scripts.

https://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.chained.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.chained.remote.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Add the following javascript after your form to initialize the jquery plugin in your doctor input:

```
{{ form(form) }}
<script>
    $("#rendez_vous_docteur").remoteChained({
        parents: "#rendez_vous_client",
        url: '{{ path('get_doctors') }}',
        clear: true,
        loading: "Loading..."
    });
</script>
```

ADIVSE: review and update as needed ids and parameters used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help, but I solved my issue by myself by simply doing a

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

I'm sorry, if you loose your time for this

PS: I followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) tutorial on symfony doc for create form events.