# dynamic select zone in a form of symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to generate dynamically the content of a selection in a form.

I have an Offre Entity who has a Competence field. Each Competence is within a group of competences called GroupeCompetences.

I want to create a form with a GroupeCompetences Select box, which will feed a second select box of competences, that are in that group.

Here are my Entities :

Offre Entity

```
/**
 * Offre
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="offre")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OffreRepository")
 */
class Offre
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var Competence
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Competence")
    */
    private $competence;

    //ALL GETTERS AND SETTERS ...
}
```

Competence Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Competence
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="competence")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CompetenceRepository")
 */
class Competence
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GroupeCompetences", inversedBy="competences")
     */
    private $groupeCompetence;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nom;

        //ALL GETTERS AND SETTERS ...
}
```

GroupeCompetences Entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * GroupeCompetences
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="groupe_competences")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GroupeCompetencesRepository")
 */
class GroupeCompetences
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Competence", mappedBy="groupeCompetence")
     */
    private $competences;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nom;

        //ALL GETTERS AND SETTERS ...
}
```

The Form (where I can not create what I explained)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Offre;

class OffreType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
        ->add('titre')
        ->add('competence')
```

This will NOT work, 
because GroupeCompetences is not directly in the Offre Entity :

```
       ->add('groupeCompetences', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:GroupeCompetences',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un groupe de compétences',
            ))
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help ! :=)

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858460/entity-is-empty-in-formmodifier-on-form-events

Comment: It is not the same case, as in the exemple the meeting entity contains the two entities (doctor and customer).
In my case I have only one entity (competence) which is linked to a group of competences. And the group is not linked with the offre entity

Comment: The case is not the same (of course), but the approach is similar, with some changes you can do what you need.

Comment: yes i see. But how do you generate in the form the groupCompetences even though it is not part of the form (because it is not in the entity) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript to make this.

first render a GroupeCompetences select. You do not need to generate this one with the formbuilder because you add javascript actions only. Just twig will be enough.

second add a new action to your controller that renders a list of options for your second select with Competences out of one given group.

third add javascript that makes an ajax request to your new action when the selected option in the GroupeCompetences select changes.

Comment: hello. I think I know how to do 2nd and 3rd. But I dont understand your number one.
What do you mean by using only twig to render a select box ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to use form events. Here is the code (maybe it could help someone ...)

```
class CompetenceChoisieType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
        ->add('groupeCompetence', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Sources\GroupeCompetences',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'placeholder' => 'Tous les groupes de compétences',
            ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, GroupeCompetences $groupeCompetences=null){
            $competences = null === $groupeCompetences ? array() : $groupeCompetences->getCompetences();

            $form->add('competence', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Sources\Competence',
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une compétence',
                'choices' => $competences,
                ));
        };


        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

                // this would be your entity, i.e. CompetenceChoisie
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getGroupeCompetence());
            }
            );

        $builder->get('groupeCompetence')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

                $groupeCompetences = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $groupeCompetences);

            }
            );
    }

}
```